# Output of string.split() method

Tags: java

I'm trying to first split a string into two values, and then split the second value in that string into more values. For some reason, the second value doesn't seem to splitting correctly.

I've tried a lot of refactoring and type checking, but it seems like the first part correctly returns a string, while the output is an array of strings, just not the strings I'm trying to return (single characters rather than the expressions separated by "|"

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String starter = "Vodafone,STOCK,10|Google,STOCK,15|Microsoft,BOND,15:Vodafone,STOCK,15|Google,STOCK,10|Microsoft,BOND,15";
        String [] newList = starter.split(":");
        for(int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(newList[i]);
        }
        String secondElement = newList[1];

        String [] secondList = secondElement.split("|");
        System.out.println(newList[1].getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(secondList.getClass().getName());
        for(int i = 0; i < secondList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(secondList[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

The result from the second for loop is just a list of individual characters, i.e. V, o, d, a, ... rather than Vodafone,STOCK,10 as the first element of the second list

Comment: try `...split("\|");` instead of `...split("|");`

Comment: `"\|" would be the JAVA string containing the JAVA escape code \|. But there is no such escape code for JAVA strings. It is necessary that the evaluated string contains "\|", so there has to be a literal "\". But \ is the escape character. To get a literal "\", you need to escape it. The correct string would be "\\|".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `'|'` character:

```
String [] secondList = secondElement.split("\\|");
```

because the argument of `split()` is a **Regex** expression and `|` is a [special **Regex** character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).